# Escape specific chars in Ruby CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to escape some specific chars in Ruby for a CSV. The chars are +-@=. Here is what I have done so far :

```
def self.to_csv
    headers =  %w{Date_de_création Civilité Nom_complet Email Téléphone Bien Agent Utilisateur}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << headers
      all.each do |contact|
        csv << [
          contact.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
          contact.gender,
          contact.full_name, contact.email,
          contact.phone,
          contact.accommodation.try(:ref_agency),
          contact.agent.try(:full_name) ,
          contact.user.try(:full_name) ].map { |attribute| escape_characters_in_string(attribute) if attribute.present? }
      end
    end
  end

  def self.escape_characters_in_string(string)
    pattern = /[=|@|+|-]/
    string.gsub(pattern) {|match| "\\" + "#{match}"}
  end
```

The output of "Areth@+=1 Fr@nklin-1" in the CSV :

```
Areth\@\+\=1 Fr\@nklin\-1
```

How would I go to escape these specific chars ?

Comment: Please define _‘escape’_.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `/[=|@|+|-]/` is a regexp that matches your four character _and_ a vertical bar. You need `[=@+-]` instead.

Comment: I do not see an error in your code. Everything works fine for me, if the only thing you want to do is add \ in front of the characters. If that is not the goal, please be more specific what you want it to do and what is it doing right now